# Boot Linux with Linux?

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, power-management

I've found [here](http://elinux.org/images/8/89/ELCE-2010-Barebox-Booting-Linux-Fast-and-Fancy.pdf) [last page] an interesting way to boot Linux by Linux. Unfortunately it is only mentioned and i can't find any useful links on the net. So has anyone heard about a method to avoid the bootloaders and instead use linux ?

Greets

Comment: The slides he's referring to http://elinux.org/images/4/45/Ipl_and_ubi.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slides he's referring to [IPL+UBI: Flexible and Reliable
with Linux as the Bootloader](http://elinux.org/images/4/45/Ipl_and_ubi.pdf) –  fvu

Answer (score 0):

Use QEMU emulator for booting linux  refer this site http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page

Comment: are you sure they mean QEMU with linux ?

Comment: Yes or you can user Virtual box also for booting any os

Comment: refer this link for QEMU http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/05/quick-quide-to-qemu-setup/

Comment: I'm pretty sure we're talking embedded systems here and "linux booting linux" as an alternative to "bootloader booting linux"...

Comment: I'm not talking about virtual devices, so this is not what I'm looking for. Linux should start Linux on embedded devices (that slides are from an embedded conference)

Comment: Refer this link for emulating arm architecture on QEMU http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/06/qemu-for-embedded-systems-development-part-1/